# Instantiate UIStoryboard at runtime in Swift2, how to handle failure?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, swift2, ios9

I am trying to load a UIStoryboard dynamically, based on some runtime condition in my app (and then instantiate the view controllers within)

Since the method `UIStoryboard(name: bundle:)` totally looks like it could fail (i.e., wrong file name, not found in bundle, etc.) I was under the assumption that it returns an optional of type `UIStoryboard?`. However, writing this code:

```
if let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "", bundle: nil) as? UIStoryboard{
    // Use the storyboard...   
}
```

...gives the warning:

> Conditional cast from 'UIStoryboard' to 'UIStoryboard' always succeeds

Because it is an initializer, the method signature in the inline documentation (option-click over the method's `name:` label) does not list a return type.

The actual web page for the documentation (pre-release, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:)) says:

> Return Value
>
> A storyboard object for the specified file. If no
>   storyboard resource file matching name exists, **an exception is thrown**
>   with description: Could not find a storyboard named 'XXXXXX' in
>   bundle....

(emphasis mine). However, attempting the do-try-catch approach gives me the warning:

> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression

So, how am I supposed to handle failure?

Comment: have you tried just running the code with the try-catch and a bogus storyboard name and see what happens?

Comment: Not yet... I just moved on to "assuming it always succeeds".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Apple doesn't handle it. If you want to get main storyboard and you don't know its name, you can try this code.

```
if let mainDict = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary {
    if let storyboardName = mainDict["UIMainStoryboardFile"] as? String {
         let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I also tried `NSBundle().mainBundle.pathForResource("StoryboardName" ofType:"storyboard")` but for some reason it always gives `nil` (perhaps the `.storyboard` extension is not supported?).

Comment: Try with
: `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("StoryboardName", ofType: "storyboardc")` because in compiled time. `storyboard` is `storyboardc`.

Comment: I will wait a little more, just in case someone sheds more light on the issue, before accepting your answer.

Comment: NP. I happy to look another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

We can also have an extension which does the same (Swift 2.0)

```
public extension UIViewController {

    public class func createInstanceFromStoryboardName(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> UIViewController? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let instance = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyboardId) as? UIViewController
        return instance
    }
}
```

Then in you class

```
if let myViewController  = UIViewController.createInstanceFromStoryboardName("UIMainStoryboardFile", storyboardId: "ID_MYVIEWCONTROLLER") as? myViewController {
// Todo
}
```

Comment: Convenient, but there is no protection in place against instantiation of the storyboard failing.

Comment: Optional chaining will take care. Read here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: No, it won't: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "fake", bundle: nil)` triggers:  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'fake' in bundle...`